# Which language should I use for [many reads, few big writes DB] with [many concurrent connections]?

Tags: vs-web-application-project, web-application-design

Which language would you recommend for use on a dynamic web-page with many users connected.  I am not using flash or anything like that, interactivity is all Javascript/HTML.

My basic two restrictions are:

- plays nicely with mySQL or if you have other specific recommendations for db I am all-ears.
- It has to be able to keep up with tons of concurrent connections that are all reading small subsets of all the content (so very cache-able) and occasionally posting plaintext (not very frequently, but voluminous -- say

I am really interested in learning a new language as a personal-programmer-expand-my-horizons initiative, so I don't want to use a java server back-end, because that's something I'm very familiar with (and I would really need something with better thread management than apache).  I'm coding proficient (but not fluent) Javascript, and would be open to JS options in addition to everything else.

Things I have looked into and figure they might be relevant, but I'm not sure how:

Node.js

Thanks for your input!

<sub>I also tagged this "web-application-design" and I feel that many programmers neglect to notice that figuring out the basic structure of your program and how the methods and objects will interoperate beforehand is absolutely 100% part of the *design* phase.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

PHP, although the choice of language is less important than the database and the storage engine used in that database. MySQL is supported by any major language nowadays.

Comment: Not sure why but the OP asked for "(and I would really need something with better thread management than apache)". php is likely thrown a yellow flag on that.

Comment: Yeah, probably. PHP should work in IIS as well, but I'm not sure if that is better. Actually, I'm pretty sure it isn't. My company runs a website, that can handle over 500 connections per second, though, running just as many queries. This is running on PHP and Apache, although the MySQL database is on a separate server.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to PHP probably being the best choice for primary language, you should also consider (If you have enough control over the server) using MEMCACHE and if you are doing very considerably more reads than writes. That would effectively allow you to cache your data in memory and that access is blazingly faster than Db lookups.

Comment: I basically have full creative control over this project, which is exciting, but I'm not familiar with all the possible technologies yet.  PHP sounds like a great starting point!  Do you have any recommendations on database software?